# GTA 5: Story Mode

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In storymode when you complete a certain mission, you get a certain outfit. For Example: "The Big One" heist. You get to keep the bank outfit. But the outfits are not saving not one of them. Does anyone know how to fix it?